# How can I modify an object's structure using jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object like this:

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  'Id': '1',
  'Username': 'Ray',
  'FatherName': 'Thompson'
}, {
  'Id': '2',
  'Username': 'Steve',
  'FatherName': 'Johnson'
}, {
  'Id': '3',
  'Username': 'Albert',
  'FatherName': 'Einstein'
}]
```

I want to convert this object structure to the following:

```js
var jsonObj = [
  ['Id': '1', 'Username': 'Ray', 'FatherName': 'Thompson'],
  ['Id': '2', 'Username': 'Steve', 'FatherName': 'Johnson'],
  ['Id': '3', 'Username': 'Albert', 'FatherName': 'Einstein']
]
```

How can I do it using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: that's not a valid json

Comment: that's not a valid json nor a valid array...

Comment: if you want to have it as a string replace the curlies with brackets

Comment: JSON.stringify([{'Id':'1','Username':'Ray','FatherName':'Thompson'},  
           {'Id':'2','Username':'Steve','FatherName':'Johnson'},
           {'Id':'3','Username':'Albert','FatherName':'Einstein'}]).replace(/{/g, '[').replace(/}/g, ']')

Comment: @mjwills i want to pass this to Jquary datatable but datatable excepting format like i have mention

Comment: `but datatable excepting format like i have mention` Can you show us the datatable docs where it says it accepts the latter format?

Comment: Note that nothing about what you have is JSON. Your first example is an object and the second is a multi-level array. I have edited the question as such

Comment: I'm pretty sure that datatable actually expects the original format. The second snippet isn't valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you converting your json data. Already jQuery datatable can use JSON object like as follows

```
var jsonObj = [{
  'Id': '1',
  'Username': 'Ray',
  'FatherName': 'Thompson'
}, {
  'Id': '2',
  'Username': 'Steve',
  'FatherName': 'Johnson'
}, {
  'Id': '3',
  'Username': 'Albert',
  'FatherName': 'Einstein'
}]

$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": jsonObj,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "Id" },
        { "mDataProp": "Username" },
        { "mDataProp": "FatherName" }
    ]
});
```

Try this once. Because I am using like this and it is working for me.

Here is the example

```js
 var jsonObj = [{
   'Id': '1',
   'Username': 'Ray',
   'FatherName': 'Thompson'
 }, {
   'Id': '2',
   'Username': 'Steve',
   'FatherName': 'Johnson'
 }, {
   'Id': '3',
   'Username': 'Albert',
   'FatherName': 'Einstein'
 }]

 $('#test').dataTable({
     "aaData": jsonObj,
     "aoColumns": [
         { "data": "Id" },
         { "data": "Username" },
         { "data": "FatherName" }
     ]
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="test"></table>
```